# display all the resolved issues since the previous build

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I have two build configurations- a dev configuration (builds on every checkin), and a QA configuration (builds on-demand, whenever a version for qa is released. We don't do continuous deployment (yet)).

When a version for QA is released, I'd like to be able to know what issues have been resolved since the last version. (format is not important- report / chart / text...),
Meaning- i'd like to know all the issues that have been changed to 'resolved' since the date of the last build in this configuration.

I'm using [tfs teamcity issue tracker](http://tfsteamcity.codeplex.com/).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You probably know already that TC has a "Fixed in Build" value?
I find it tricky to use because if we click 'build' once too often, the list of resolved issues gets all messed up.

Thus I'm also interested in expanding the feature, I just posted; 
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/438721
API to access "Fixed in Build" value?